# weblogic persistent store error

Tags: weblogic, datasource

I have a cluster with 2 OSB servers. There is a datasource targeted on both servers, and two persistent stores associated with the servers.
At server startup the following error message appears only on the first server. The table and the store existed previously, and they worked fine.

```
<Error> <Store> <BEA-280061> <The persistent store "JDBCStore" could not be deployed: weblogic.store.io.jdbc.JDBCStoreException: [Store:280065]open failed (server="OSBServer1" store="JDBCStore" table="jms3_WLStore"):(Linked Cause, "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'OSB_JMS'
")
```

Comment: Sounds like a permissions/quota issue. What have you checked? Reference: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01950_no+priviledges_on_tablespace_string.htm and https://community.oracle.com/message/10255115?tstart=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to check the permissions on the DB side

ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'OSB_JMS'

Cause: User does not have privileges to allocate an extent in the specified tablespace.

Action: Grant the user the appropriate system privileges or grant the user space resource on the tablespace.

Thus it indicate that there is an issue on the DB w.r.t permissions on the table space. You might also need to check if you are using the correct user in the datasource configuration for the persistent store if it was working for you before and nothing has changed on the WLS server.

Cheers!!